# Catkin fails to chain workspaces

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I have a problem and cannot find a permanent solution to it:

I am trying to chain two workspaces A and B but catkin fails to recognize workspace A.
So what i did was create worspace A in:

```
/usr/share/ros/workspaceA
```

This works fine and i can build my packages.
Then i created another workspace B to work in, this should overlay workspace A, in:

```
~/ros/workspaceB
```

My packages in workspaceB depend on packages in workspace A.
When trying

```
source /usr/share/ros/workspaceA/devel/setup.bash
source ~/ros/workspaceB/devel/setup.bash
cd ~/ros/workspaceB/
catkin_make
```

I get

```
...
-- This workspace overlays: ~/ros/workspaceB/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
...
```

and following some error that my package from workspaceA ould not be found.
So obviously, catkin fails to recognize workspaceA. Without dependencies on packages from workspaceA everything works fine.

How do I get this fixed, so that i can build my packages in workspaceB? What am I missing? Has this to do with the path to workspaceA?

Note:
This worked for me once, when workspaceA was located in

```
~/ros/workspaceA
```

but after deleting it and recreating in in just the same place i got the same result as above.

Thanks for your support!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190536/catkin-fails-to-chain-workspaces/) by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2016-11-16**:
This has a way nicer solution with `catkin tools`. See http://answers.ros.org/question/64702/overlaying-multiple-catkin-devel-spaces-at-the-same-time/?answer=248245#post-id-248245 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is the assumption that sourcing chains workspaces. This is not the case. If it were sourcing multiple `setup.sh` files will leave you in an undefined state depending on whatever you did before. Here is your problem:

```
source /usr/share/ros/workspaceA/devel/setup.bash
source ~/ros/workspaceB/devel/setup.bash
cd ~/ros/workspaceB/
catkin_make
```

This activates workspaceB before building. Thus you do not overlay workspaceA.
Check out the tutorial on [chaining workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces). Note the lines along:

```
## THIS IS THE CRUCIAL PART FOR OVERLAYING
$ source ~/overlay_ws/devel/setup.bash
$ catkin_make
```

You probably at some point sourced workspaceA and `catkin_make` in workspaceB leading to this:

```
-- This workspace overlays: ~/ros/workspaceB/devel;/usr/share/ros/workspaceA/devel;~/ros/workspaceB/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
```

Try removing the build/devel folders in workspaceB and then:

```
source /usr/share/ros/workspaceA/devel/setup.bash
cd ~/ros/workspaceB/
catkin_make
source ~/ros/workspaceB/devel/setup.bash
```

This should lead to the setup you want. From now on it is sufficient to
`source ~/ros/workspaceB/devel/setup.bash` in your .bashrc. This will lead to the correct overlays.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2014-08-19**:
Thank you. Think I messed things up trying to understand chaining workspaces.
Just edited my question to remove the last (misleading) edit.

So one could say that it's always building before sourcing?

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-19**:
That depends. Build your current workspace before sourcing it, but source other (underlaid) workspaces (which were already built at some point) before building the current one (otherwise, workspaces will not be chained).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sourcing in the correct order does not actually guarantee workspaces will be chained correctly, and the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH may have repeated entries (as described in the question). The details can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces). This link also describes the limitations in chaining catkin workspaces.

It is all down to which ROS installation and user workspace(s) were already sourced at the time the new workspace was created.

To illustrate that, suppose the `.bashrc` file is only sourcing my hydro (or indigo) installation:

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

We can check the environment variable:

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

Then, in `terminal #1` we create a workspace named `A`, build and source it:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/A/src
$ cd ~/A/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
...
$ cd ../
$ catkin_make
...
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

If we check the environment variable again:

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/user/temp/A/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

In (a new) `terminal #2`, we create another workspace, named B (remember, only the system-wide ROS installation is being sourced in my .bashrc). After building and sourcing it in `terminal #2`, if we check the env. variable in this case:

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/user/temp/B/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

So far so good. Let us now add the necessary lines to the `.bashrc` file in order to source workspaces A and B:

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source /home/user/temp/A/devel/setup.bash
source /home/user/temp/B/devel/setup.bash
```

Again, in (a new) `terminal #3`, if we check the env. variable:

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/user/temp/B/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

Only workspace `B` (as well as the system-wide installation) was sourced. This shows that sourcing in the correct order does not imply in chaining workspaces correctly (as documented in the link above).

Now, back to `terminal #1`, where workspace `A` is properly sourced, let us create workspace `C`, build and source it. Then, let us check the environment variable:

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/user/temp/C/src:/home/user/temp/A/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

This time, workspace `C` was correctly chained with workspace `A`, and the reason for that to have worked as expected is because workspace `A` was already sourced in `terminal #1`, which was not the case in `terminal #2`.

To be more pedantic with my explanation, if one tried the sequence of commands above and ran a diff (say, using meld) between the automatically generated files `/home/user/temp/A/devel/_setup_util.py`, `/home/user/temp/B/devel/_setup_util.py` and `/home/user/temp/C/devel/_setup_util.py`, one would find that those files from workspaces `A` and `B` are identical, whilst in the file referring to workspace `C`, line 255, the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable would include `/home/user/temp/A/devel`, because workspace `A` was already sourced.

I hope this helps others to avoid having the issues I had in the past.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2014-08-19**:
Thank you for your answer, it just helped me understanding the concept of overlaying workspaces.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2014-11-11**:
Thanks for pointing out where to edit the CMAKE_PREFX_PATH. It becomes much easier for me to chain or unchain the workspaces. Thx.